# Errors installing ocaml using homebrew on OS X

Tags: macos, homebrew, unison

I'm trying to install objective-ocaml on my Mac to compile another application (Unison) I would like to install however I'm getting errors doing so.

```
    imrans-mac:/ Imran$ brew doctor Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

    objective-caml 

    imrans-mac:/ Imran$ brew link objective-caml Linking /usr/local/Cellar/objective-caml/4.01.0... Warning: Could not link objective-caml. Unlinking...

    Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/objective-caml/4.01.0/lib/ocaml/weak.p.cmx Target /usr/local/lib/ocaml/weak.p.cmx already exists. You may need to delete it. To force the link and overwrite all other conflicting files, do:   brew link --overwrite formula_name

    To list all files that would be deleted:   brew link --overwrite
    --dry-run formula_name imrans-mac:/ Imran$ brew link --overwrite objective-ocaml Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/objective-ocaml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, run `brew doctor`. This should clean up any permission errors. Also usually solves most problems.

Note this in the error log:

```
brew link --overwrite formula_name
```

Try that in there as well. The big issue here is that the file/folder permissions do not allow you to write or `symlink` there.

To fix permissions you may need to [try this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions)

```
sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local
```

I just tried installing unison as well, no issues on my end.

Comment: Sorry the formatting of my log is terrible, if you look at the bottom line I have tried the -overwrite argument. It says theres `no such keg`...

Comment: @Imran Try `brew doctor`. It should fix permission errors. Also `brew update`. Uninstall the current builds of unison/objective-caml and make sure the folders are cleared.

Comment: I have used both `brew doctor` and `brew update`, they dont do anything. When using `brew rm objective-ocaml` it returns **No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/objective-ocaml**

Comment: @Imran if you have used sudo before it can mess up permissions. try `sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local`

Comment: @Imran did that fix it?

Comment: Yeah the permissions were the issue as I have used `sudo` before. After fixing permissions I was able to use `brew link` to fix ocaml and install unison. Thank you!